# Start X from remote

Tags: x11, remote, startx

I have a stand sitting between my two monitors. Atop it sits my work laptop, and on a lower level in the stand sits my own laptop, which is always closed. The monitors are identical and each has 2 HDMI ports, and 1 DisplayPort. My desktop PC(running linux) is connected to HDMI-1 on each monitor, and my linux laptop(running linux) is connected to the DisplayPorts. The work laptop is not connected to any external displays.

I want to be able to switch between my desktop and laptop, both running X, and I don't want to run a display manager, as I do not want to devote the resources to it. I start X with xorg's `startx` command, and the technical pickle I can't seem to get past is how to execute `startx` without moving my keyboard aside, pulling the laptop out, and typing `startx` on it. I've tried executing it with `at(now + 0)` but it doesn't appear to work.

Is it possible to execute `startx` remotely? If so, how can I do it?

To clarify, I am not interested in running X applications remotely. I am trying to start X on a remote machine, so it can be running when i switch to it.

Comment: `ssh -qf remoteServer screen -md startx` perhaps? (I can't test this, hence it being a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: @roaima Confirmed: it doesn't work. Not with tmux either, btw.

Comment: "I don't want to run a display manager, as I do not want to devote the resources to it" Bad idea.

Comment: There's some discussion of starting X in archlinux [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_login_into_Xorg_without_display_manager). It might provide some ideas.